# VB.net's IsNumeric views £ as numeric?

Tags: vb.net

This is a little confusing, why is it like this?

```
Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("$0")) - False

Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("€0")) - False

Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("£0")) - True

Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("£")) - False
```

Seems pretty weird to me, what's the reason it does this

Edit: works on the end as well:

```
Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("300£")) - True

Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("300£0")) - False

Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("£300£")) - False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Living in Italy - running on Italian locale

```
Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("$0")) ' False
Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("€0")) ' True
Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("£0")) ' False
Console.WriteLine(IsNumeric("£"))  ' False
```

while this will give you back always true

```
using System.Globalization;

Console.WriteLine(MyIsNumeric("$0", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, "en-US"))
Console.WriteLine(MyIsNumeric("€0", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, "it-IT")) 
Console.WriteLine(MyIsNumeric("£0", NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, "en-GB")) 


Public Function MyIsNumeric(ByVal val as String, ByVal NumberStyle as NumberStyles, cName as String) as Boolean
    Dim result as Double
    return Double.TryParse(val,NumberStyle, new CultureInfo(cName), result)
 End Function
```

So we could conclude that IsNumeric (originally defined in VB6 runtime) is `smart` enough to exclude from its parsing the current locale currency symbols if they precede or follow the input string.

Comment: Yes, i agree. Compatibility I suppose.